# Oracle Prepared Statement - ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Tags: java, sql, date, oracle11g, wildcard

I am currently trying to insert dates into my local Oracle database, the insert is written within a java JAR file which uses wildcards. The INSERT works if I send the dates as null however when I attempt to send a date I get the following error:

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

I have ran two SQL commands:

```
SELECT PARAMETER, VALUE FROM v$nls_parameters;

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

Which return this data:

```
PARAMETER                                                        VALUE                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                                                     ENGLISH                                                          
NLS_TERRITORY                                                    UNITED KINGDOM                                                   
NLS_CURRENCY                                                     £                                                                
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY                                                 UNITED KINGDOM                                                   
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS                                           .,                                                               
NLS_CALENDAR                                                     GREGORIAN                                                        
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                                                  DD-MON-RR                                                        
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE                                                ENGLISH                                                          
NLS_CHARACTERSET                                                 AL32UTF8                                                         
NLS_SORT                                                         BINARY                                                           
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                                                  HH24.MI.SSXFF                                                    
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT                                             DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF                                          
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT                                               HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR                                                
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT                                          DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR                                      
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY                                                €                                                                
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET                                           AL16UTF16                                                        
NLS_COMP                                                         BINARY                                                           
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS                                             BYTE                                                             
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP                                              FALSE                                                            

 19 rows selected 

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                  
------------------------------------
16-JAN-14 08.03.06.437000000 EUROPE/ 
LONDON
```

After looking at the data above I attempted to amend my prepared statement to match the timestamps shown:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(?,'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR')

TO_TIMESTAMP(?,'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF')
```

Where ? is the wildcard value that I am passing in using java i.e. `interaction.getStartDate();`

Does anyone know how to find the correct format or where I am going wrong? I have looked online for the last couple of days and am completely baffled.

Comment: Why do you need a date format? Date formats are for converting between strings and date.

Comment: I am not in control of the database settings and the field has been set up as a TIMESTAMP

Comment: There are dates in the database already, and example of one of these is: 17-JUL-13 15.31.07.000000000

Comment: But the JDBC driver should take care of that. You just bind a java.util.Date or java.sql.Date object (or java.sql.Timestamp, if you need fractions of seconds), and the JDBC driver should map that to a correct SQL statement. BTW, your example (17-JUL-13 15.31.07.000000000) does not show how timestamps are stored, only how they are presented (as a sting), when you fetch it.

Comment: @MrBackend: java.util.Date can't be bound. java.sql.Date is for date without time, and java.sql.Timestamp is for date and time. I agree that this is the right solution, though.

Comment: Currently the java object has a String value for the date, I attempted to change this to a Date object and pass a date through to Oracle, this worked and stored a Date however the Date stored was not the date I sent.

Comment: Sorry, my bad about java.util.Date. It works in Hibernate, that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: Ok I shall try to send an sql.timestamp object now and get back to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the date to store into the database correctly after some tests. The date format that I used in the TO_TIMESTAMP call was 'DD-Mon-RRRR HH:MI:SS PM', full insert shown below:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(?,'DD-Mon-RRRR HH:MI:SS PM')
```

Comment: to find the format required I System.out.printed the string value of the date within my object.